# dragging and resizing an image on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am building a HTML5 canvas image editor. After uploading an image in to the canvas i need to Dragg and resize it over the canvas.
I managed to upload an image and make it draggable on the canvas. But i need to make it resizable also along the canvas. Thanks in advance.

```
var Img = new Image();
Img.src = file;
Img.onload = function () {
  context.drawImage(Img, 50, 0, 200, 200); 
}
mouseMove = function (event){
if (down) 
{
 context.clearRect(0,0,800,500);
 context.translate(0, -50); 
 context.drawImage(Img, (event.clientX - offsetX),
 (event.clientY - offsetY), 200, 200);
 context.translate(0, 50);
}
}
mouseUp = function () {
  down = false;
}
mouseDown = function () {
  down = true;
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',mouseMove, false);
```

I tried with kinetics js but it is not suitable with canvas.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's example code to allow you to drag and resize an image using Canvas.

**Resizing**

[image][image]

**How to resize an image with 4 draggable anchors**

- Draw a draggable anchor on each corner of an image.
- If the user mousedown’s one if the anchors, start dragging that anchor.
- In the mousemove handler, resize the image using the dragging anchor’s position(Note below).
- As the last act in mousemove, redraw the resized image and 4 new anchors.
- On mouseup, stop the anchor’s drag.

Note on the math used to resize the image:

- The resized width is the difference between the mouseX position and the opposite corner’s X.
- The resized height is the difference between the mouseY position and the opposite corner’s Y.

**Dragging**

[image][image]

**How to drag an image**

- If the user mousedown’s inside the image, save the mouses starting XY to begin dragging.
- In the mousemove handler, move the image by the current mouseXY minus the startingXY.
- Also in mousemove, reset the startingXY to the current mouseXY in preparation for continued dragging.
- On mouseup, stop the image’s drag.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LAS8L/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px;}
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
    
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;


    var pi2=Math.PI*2;
    var resizerRadius=8;
    var rr=resizerRadius*resizerRadius;
    var draggingResizer={x:0,y:0};
    var imageX=50;
    var imageY=50;
    var imageWidth,imageHeight,imageRight,imageBottom;
    var draggingImage=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;


   
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        imageWidth=img.width;
        imageHeight=img.height;
        imageRight=imageX+imageWidth;
        imageBottom=imageY+imageHeight
        draw(true,false);
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";


    function draw(withAnchors,withBorders){

        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // draw the image
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,imageX,imageY,imageWidth,imageHeight);

        // optionally draw the draggable anchors
        if(withAnchors){
            drawDragAnchor(imageX,imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight,imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight,imageBottom);
            drawDragAnchor(imageX,imageBottom);
        }
        
        // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
        if(withBorders){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(imageX,imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight,imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight,imageBottom);
            ctx.lineTo(imageX,imageBottom);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    }

    function drawDragAnchor(x,y){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,resizerRadius,0,pi2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function anchorHitTest(x,y){

        var dx,dy;

        // top-left
        dx=x-imageX;
        dy=y-imageY;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=rr){ return(0); }
        // top-right
        dx=x-imageRight;
        dy=y-imageY;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=rr){ return(1); }
        // bottom-right
        dx=x-imageRight;
        dy=y-imageBottom;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=rr){ return(2); }
        // bottom-left
        dx=x-imageX;
        dy=y-imageBottom;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=rr){ return(3); }
        return(-1);

    }


    function hitImage(x,y){
        return(x>imageX && x<imageX+imageWidth && y>imageY && y<imageY+imageHeight);
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      draggingResizer=anchorHitTest(startX,startY);
      draggingImage= draggingResizer<0 && hitImage(startX,startY);
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      draggingResizer=-1;
      draggingImage=false;
      draw(true,false);
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      handleMouseUp(e);
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      
      if(draggingResizer>-1){
      
          mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
          mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

          // resize the image
          switch(draggingResizer){
              case 0: //top-left
                  imageX=mouseX;
                  imageWidth=imageRight-mouseX;
                  imageY=mouseY;
                  imageHeight=imageBottom-mouseY;
                  break;
              case 1: //top-right
                  imageY=mouseY;
                  imageWidth=mouseX-imageX;
                  imageHeight=imageBottom-mouseY;
                  break;
              case 2: //bottom-right
                  imageWidth=mouseX-imageX;
                  imageHeight=mouseY-imageY;
                  break;
              case 3: //bottom-left
                  imageX=mouseX;
                  imageWidth=imageRight-mouseX;
                  imageHeight=mouseY-imageY;
                  break;
          }

          // enforce minimum dimensions of 25x25
          if(imageWidth<25){imageWidth=25;}
          if(imageHeight<25){imageHeight=25;}

          // set the image right and bottom
          imageRight=imageX+imageWidth;
          imageBottom=imageY+imageHeight;
          
          // redraw the image with resizing anchors
          draw(true,true);
      
      }else if(draggingImage){
      
          imageClick=false;
          
          mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
          mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
          
          // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
          var dx=mouseX-startX;
          var dy=mouseY-startY;
          imageX+=dx;
          imageY+=dy;
          imageRight+=dx;
          imageBottom+=dy;
          // reset the startXY for next time
          startX=mouseX;
          startY=mouseY;
          
          // redraw the image with border
          draw(false,true);
          
      }
      
      
    }


    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

       
}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Resize the image using the 4 draggable corner anchors</p>
    <p>You can also drag the image</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried with it but not able to make it working with drawing Image using 'context.DrawImage'. Can you help me bydrawing images rather than rectangles by editing simson sarris code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You are always very helpful. May god bless you.

Comment: I am curios to know how to implement rotate event also on the image.

Comment: The context will rotate your image+resizers. But when hittesting in mouse handlers, you'll have to un-rotate the mouseXY (because that XY is given in unrotated space) So...Drawing with rotation: ctx.save(); ctx.rotate(radianAngle); // draw image and resizers normally ctx.restore();  But in your mouse events, you'll have to track the image and resizers by unrotating mouseXY for the rotation:  unrotatedX=centerX+mouseX*Math.cos(-radianAngle)-mouseY*Math.sin(-radianAngle);
 unrotatedY=centerY-mouseX*Math.sin(-radianAngle)-mouseY*Math.cos(-radianAngle);

Comment: I tried my level best to implement rotate feature also in to the above code in yours fiddle using your suggestions. But i could not succeed. It might be because of my inexperience. Can you please help me by adding the the code of rotating also to the fiddle.

Comment: Instead of adding rotation to your question after your original question has been fully answered, you should simply ask a new separate question about rotation.

Comment: Sorry. I meant that how to add rotation part also to the existing fiddle of yours.

Comment: @markE.  Your answer very helpfull for me. If you don't mind, I want to know how to do upload image by user. can you see this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653644/uploaded-image-in-canvas-drag-touchable-and-rotatable-in-html5

Comment: Hi nice answer, what would I need to do to scale a drawn square like the image. For example if I draw a square and want to scale it

Comment: @markE know that this is an old thread, but I think those topics will never end. I have opened my own thread about that topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367459/canvas-change-size-of-drawings-live/45368489) and do kinda have the same problem. But instead of moving a specific image I want the user to be able to select a specific area by drawing a transparent border and then moving and resizing this rectangle. Can you help me out?

Comment: In jsfiddle example, the link to image is broken - 404