# In html5, Javascript is there a way to make a polygon I just draw draggable? or listen to mouse events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, jquery-events

I draw a polygon with the following code:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("polyCanvas");
    var c2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var coords = '';

    c2.clearRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    $("fdel").remove();
    $("#eliminar" + todelete).remove();
    c2.beginPath();

    var first = true;
    var points = 1;
    var done = false;
    $("#vertexcontainer .vertex").each(function() {
        var position = $(this).position();
        var x = 2+position.left;
        var y = 2+position.top;
        if (!done){
            if (first) {
                c2.moveTo(x, y);
                first = false;
            } else {
                c2.lineTo(x, y);
            }
        }
        if(points > cpoints){
            done = true;
        }
        points = points + 1;
        coords = coords + x + ',' + y + ' ';
    });
    $('#coordinates').val(coords);;
    c2.closePath();
    c2.lineWidth = 2;
    c2.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    c2.stroke();
    c2.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 100, 200)";
    c2.fill();
```

It runs smoothly, but i'd like to be able to drag the polygon around, or to use mouse events with it. Is that possible?

My naive attempt to do `c2.hover(function..., and c2.addeventlistener...` have not been successful.

Comment: I think this is a helpful and complete answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100009/dragging-and-resizing-an-image-on-html5-canvas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dragging and resizing an image on html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100009/dragging-and-resizing-an-image-on-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot actually move any drawings you've made on the canvas.

But...*you can create the illusion that something is moving*.

You create the illusion of movement by repeatedly erasing the canvas and redrawing the shapes in their new positions.

To drag a shape you need to listen to 4 mouse events.

**In mousedown:** Check if the mouse is over the shape, and, if yes, set a flag indicating a drag has begun. To check if the mouse is over the shape, you can use canvas context's `isPointInPath` method which tests if an [x,y] point is inside the most recently drawn path.

**In mousemove:** If the dragging flag is set (indicating a drag is in process), change the position of the selected text by the distance the user has dragged and redraw the shape in its new position

**In mouseup or in mouseout:** The drag is over so clear the dragging flag.

*Here's a example code and a Demo:*

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var poly={
  x:0,
  y:0,
  points:[{x:50,y:50},{x:75,y:25},{x:100,y:50},{x:75,y:125},{x:50,y:50}],
}

ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.strokeStyle='gray';
ctx.lineWidth=3;

draw();

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});


function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  define();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke()
}

function define(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(poly.points[0].x+poly.x,poly.points[0].y+poly.y);
  for(var i=0;i<poly.points.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(poly.points[i].x+poly.x,poly.points[i].y+poly.y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  define();
  if(ctx.isPointInPath(startX,startY)){
    isDown=true;
  }
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseOut stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousemove stuff here
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;

  poly.x+=dx;
  poly.y+=dy;
  draw();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag the polygon</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```