# Image not loading in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a code that is used to re-size and drag/drop an image within the canvas.
The problem is the image won't show. I have seen this code in other websites and it works for them (apparently), is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

I have tried making the image resolution smaller than the canvas' but still to no avail.

Following is my HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="resizing.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {
    background-color: ivory;
    padding:10px;
}
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
```

Following is my js:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;


var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
var resizerRadius = 8;
var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
var draggingResizer = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
var imageX = 50;
var imageY = 50;
var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
var draggingImage = false;
var startX;
var startY;



var init = function(){
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    imageWidth = img.width;
    imageHeight = img.height;
    imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
    imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
    draw(true, false);
}
img.src = "Newzeign.jpg";
};
window.addEventListener("load",init);

function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {

    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw the image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    // optionally draw the draggable anchors
    if (withAnchors) {
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
    }

    // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
    if (withBorders) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
        ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}

function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function anchorHitTest(x, y) {

    var dx, dy;

    // top-left
    dx = x - imageX;
    dy = y - imageY;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (0);
    }
    // top-right
    dx = x - imageRight;
    dy = y - imageY;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (1);
    }
    // bottom-right
    dx = x - imageRight;
    dy = y - imageBottom;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (2);
    }
    // bottom-left
    dx = x - imageX;
    dy = y - imageBottom;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (3);
    }
    return (-1);

}


function hitImage(x, y) {
    return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
}


function handleMouseDown(e) {
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(startX, startY);
    draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(startX, startY);
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    draggingResizer = -1;
    draggingImage = false;
    draw(true, false);
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {

    if (draggingResizer > -1) {

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // resize the image
        switch (draggingResizer) {
            case 0:
                //top-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
            case 1:
                //top-right
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
            case 2:
                //bottom-right
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
            case 3:
                //bottom-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
        }

        if(imageWidth<25){imageWidth=25;}
        if(imageHeight<25){imageHeight=25;}

        // set the image right and bottom
        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;

        // redraw the image with resizing anchors
        draw(true, true);

    } else if (draggingImage) {

        imageClick = false;

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
        var dx = mouseX - startX;
        var dy = mouseY - startY;
        imageX += dx;
        imageY += dy;
        imageRight += dx;
        imageBottom += dy;
        // reset the startXY for next time
        startX = mouseX;
        startY = mouseY;

        // redraw the image with border
        draw(false, true);

    }


}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});

$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you're using my code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100009/dragging-and-resizing-an-image-on-html5-canvas/19101826#19101826). :-p

- Load the **entire script** after the window is loaded. To do that...don't wrap just part of the code in that `init` wrapper and don't use that window.onload listener.
- Wrap the **entire script** in `$(function(){<script>...all the JS code...</script>}` so that it loads after the DOM is loaded.
- The script requires jQuery -- I don't see where you loaded it so include jQuery: `<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`
- Make sure your image file (Newzeign.jpg) is in the same folder as this the webpage code (.html, .css, .js AND Newzeign.jpg all in the same folder).

**Here's refactored (verified working) code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown = false;

    var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var resizerRadius = 8;
    var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
    var draggingResizer = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    var imageX = 50;
    var imageY = 50;
    var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
    var draggingImage = false;
    var startX;
    var startY;

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        imageWidth = img.width;
        imageHeight = img.height;
        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
        draw(true, false);
    }
    img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/flower.png";

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) { handleMouseDown(e); });
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) { handleMouseMove(e); });
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {   handleMouseUp(e); });
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) { handleMouseOut(e); });

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {
        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // draw the image
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

        // optionally draw the draggable anchors
        if (withAnchors) {
            drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
            drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
        }

        // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
        if (withBorders) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
            ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function anchorHitTest(x, y) {
        var dx, dy;

        // top-left
        dx = x - imageX;
        dy = y - imageY;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) { return (0); }
        // top-right
        dx = x - imageRight;
        dy = y - imageY;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) { return (1); }
        // bottom-right
        dx = x - imageRight;
        dy = y - imageBottom;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) { return (2); }
        // bottom-left
        dx = x - imageX;
        dy = y - imageBottom;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) { return (3); }
        return (-1);
    }

    function hitImage(x, y) {
        return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e) {
        startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
        draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(startX, startY);
        draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(startX, startY);
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e) {
        draggingResizer = -1;
        draggingImage = false;
        draw(true, false);
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e) {
        handleMouseUp(e);
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        if (draggingResizer > -1) {

            mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            // resize the image
            switch (draggingResizer) {
                case 0:
                    //top-left
                    imageX = mouseX;
                    imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                    imageY = mouseY;
                    imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //top-right
                    imageY = mouseY;
                    imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                    imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //bottom-right
                    imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                    imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //bottom-left
                    imageX = mouseX;
                    imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                    imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                    break;
            }

            if(imageWidth<25){imageWidth=25;}
            if(imageHeight<25){imageHeight=25;}

            // set the image right and bottom
            imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
            imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;

            // redraw the image with resizing anchors
            draw(true, true);

        } else if (draggingImage) {

            imageClick = false;

            mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
            var dx = mouseX - startX;
            var dy = mouseY - startY;
            imageX += dx;
            imageY += dy;
            imageRight += dx;
            imageBottom += dy;
            // reset the startXY for next time
            startX = mouseX;
            startY = mouseY;

            // redraw the image with border
            draw(false, true);
        }
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here's a working demo:**

```js
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
        var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
        var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
        var startX;
        var startY;
        var isDown = false;

        var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
        var resizerRadius = 8;
        var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
        var draggingResizer = {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        };
        var imageX = 50;
        var imageY = 50;
        var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
        var draggingImage = false;
        var startX;
        var startY;

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
          imageWidth = img.width;
          imageHeight = img.height;
          imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
          imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
          draw(true, false);
        }
        img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/flower.png";

        $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
          handleMouseDown(e);
        });
        $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
          handleMouseMove(e);
        });
        $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e) {
          handleMouseUp(e);
        });
        $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e) {
          handleMouseOut(e);
        });

         //////////////////////////////////////////////

        function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {
          // clear the canvas
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          // draw the image
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

          // optionally draw the draggable anchors
          if (withAnchors) {
            drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
            drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
          }

          // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
          if (withBorders) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
            ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
          }
        }

        function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill();
        }

        function anchorHitTest(x, y) {
          var dx, dy;

          // top-left
          dx = x - imageX;
          dy = y - imageY;
          if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
            return (0);
          }
          // top-right
          dx = x - imageRight;
          dy = y - imageY;
          if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
            return (1);
          }
          // bottom-right
          dx = x - imageRight;
          dy = y - imageBottom;
          if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
            return (2);
          }
          // bottom-left
          dx = x - imageX;
          dy = y - imageBottom;
          if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
            return (3);
          }
          return (-1);
        }

        function hitImage(x, y) {
          return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
        }

        function handleMouseDown(e) {
          startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
          startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
          draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(startX, startY);
          draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(startX, startY);
        }

        function handleMouseUp(e) {
          draggingResizer = -1;
          draggingImage = false;
          draw(true, false);
        }

        function handleMouseOut(e) {
          handleMouseUp(e);
        }

        function handleMouseMove(e) {
          if (draggingResizer > -1) {

            mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            // resize the image
            switch (draggingResizer) {
              case 0:
                //top-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
              case 1:
                //top-right
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
              case 2:
                //bottom-right
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
              case 3:
                //bottom-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
            }

            if (imageWidth < 25) {
              imageWidth = 25;
            }
            if (imageHeight < 25) {
              imageHeight = 25;
            }

            // set the image right and bottom
            imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
            imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;

            // redraw the image with resizing anchors
            draw(true, true);

          } else if (draggingImage) {

            imageClick = false;

            mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
            var dx = mouseX - startX;
            var dy = mouseY - startY;
            imageX += dx;
            imageY += dy;
            imageRight += dx;
            imageBottom += dy;
            // reset the startXY for next time
            startX = mouseX;
            startY = mouseY;

            // redraw the image with border
            draw(false, true);
          }
        }
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```

Comment: I found your answer (I think) and then followed the javascript fiddle link.
First I'd like to apologize for using your code without you permission, the code was supplied already so I thought it wouldnt matter.
Secondly, I tried including everything in "$(document).ready(function(){//code here});" and I included jquery (and tested if it really is included) but still the image isn't loading. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: No apology needed -- if you use code from Stackoverflow you only must give the author attribution and cite the SO Q&A where you got the code. I've added full code made with the changes in my answer. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for your help!
And I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// I cut out the rest of the code to make answer shorter...

var init = function()
{
     var img = new Image();
     img.onload = function ()
     {
            imageWidth = img.width;
        imageHeight = img.height;
        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
        draw(true, false);
    }
    img.src = "Newzeign.jpg";
};
window.addEventListener("load",init);
```

This will make sure that the page is loaded before it tries to get the image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the file is already in the same folder as the HTML.

Comment: Still no difference..
I am including the whole js file, maybe there is a problem somewhere else.
I would also like to add that Im new to javascript, but I do know java, are there any libraries I have to include that Im missing (or are there libraries?)  
thank you again

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be that the DOM is not ready yet, the html canvas loads before the Javascript but the script has not been run.

One way is to call a method for

```
document. onload=function (){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
    imageWidth = img.width;
    imageHeight = img.height;
     imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
    imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
     draw(true, false);
}
img.src = "Newzeign.jpg";

   } ;
```

Or you could put the entire script code into a function like this.

```
function callThisOnload (){

     //put all the javascript in here

}
```

Then place in the body tag the callThisOnload () function like this.

```
  <body onload="callThisOnload ()">
```

This will let the code run immediately when the DOM is loaded and the the image will be loaded into the canvas

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work again. Maybe I made some other mistake..
Im including the whole js code this time, maybe there is a problem somewhere else?