# How to make my picture resizable using angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone i have a lot of problems to make my picture resizable (when i put my pointer on the edges of the picture) using Angular js can anyone please help me how can i make script functional?. Here is my Html ...

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 ">


     <img class="img-responsive " src="assets/images/coca-cola.jpg" alt="" />


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean resizable? real time update ?

Comment: i like to resize my picture when i move my mouse cursor on some edge of the picture. tnx

Comment: you reject my edit? :3

Comment: no can you post again.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is using CSS `resize` property.

```
<div style="overflow:auto;resize:both;">
    <img style="width:100%;height:auto;" class="img-responsive " src="assets/images/coca-cola.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Then you can use `ng-mouseover` to trigger that style or class using `ng-style` or `ng-class`

Comment: Thanks Jack it work good but i have little problem because picture is in <div> and i resize "div" not picture

Comment: The image size is set to 100% width of its parent. Whe you change the wrapper div's size, image changes correspondingly. If you want to literally resize image, I suggest using canvas, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100009/dragging-and-resizing-an-image-on-html5-canvas